# Customer attribute different stores

Tags: magento2, multistore, customer-attribute

I have customer attribute and I would like to this attribute is required in first store, not required in second store.

I have one solution, I would like create second customer attribute in a similar code and in first store use first attribute, in second store use second attribute. But I don't know how to set scope for customer attribute. Any hints?

$installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

```
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
        'customer_address',
        'company',
        'is_required',
        true
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

An example to add an attribute and how to precise the scope, you can update an attribute with the same method:

```
    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
        {

            $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            // add customer_attribute to customer
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute');
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Customer Attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'system' => 0,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'sort_order' => '200'
            ]
        );

}
```

Comment: how to implement in code by upgradeAttribute() ? I set that only is_required without scope website

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: I added code ...

Comment: This is product attribute, I need customer attribute

Comment: Ok, where I can set id by second store for second attribute?

Comment: Did you try to add website_id=>? in the code?